# find command: how to ignore pathname?

Tags: files, find, directory, path, cut

I have to find some type of files in a directory and it's subdirectories and I only have to print out the filenames. 
So here's the main command:
`find -type f -name "*.c"`

Now, how could I cut the paths from each result? (it possibily could be done with awk, but I hope, that there's an easier way to do that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU find supports the `-printf` predicate, which supports the `%f` format specifier for outputting on the filename.

```
find -type f -name "*.c" -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: answered so fast. tried out. thanks again ! :D

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk` is not so complicated:

```
find . -name '*.c' -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Or `sed`:

```
find . -name '*.c' -type f | LC_ALL=C sed 's|.*/||'
```

(assuming file paths don't contain newline characters) and that will work with any `find` implementation.

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*.c(N.:t)
```

Comment: Assuming file names **and** path directory names don't contain newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `basename` program to get the file name:

```
find . -type f -name \*.c -exec basename {} +
```

This works on `find`s that don't have the GNU `-printf` extension.

Comment: If `basename` is given more than one argument, the 2nd is taken as a suffix to strip, and more than 2 arguments would typically cause an error. With GNU `basename`, you could use `-exec basename -a {} +`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU find knows `-printf`. If you search subdirectories, too, then file names can occur multiple times (in general)!

You need `-printf "%p\n"` or `-printf "%f\n"`.