# Exclude path from file name for 'find .' command

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have a Master folder with following subfolders:

- f1
- f2

with jpeg/jpg files in each subfolder.
I do `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '*.jp*g'` and getting output:

- ./f1/IM_48902.jpg
- ./f1/IM_48903.jpg
- ./f2/IM_48900.jpg
- ./f2/IM_48904.jpg

How I can exclude '/f1' and '/f2' from output and get such output?

- ./IM_48902.jpg
- ./IM_48903.jpg
- ./IM_48900.jpg
- ./IM_48904.jpg

[UPD] my full script is `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '.jpg' ! -path "/excluded/" -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 -n1 -P3 sh -c 'exiv2 -q -K Xmp.dc.creator -K Xmp.photoshop.Credit -Pv "$1" > "/Users/adm/Desktop/$1.out"' -- {}`

Comment: Wich `find` version from which OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find command: how to ignore pathname?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76466/find-command-how-to-ignore-pathname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU find, use the `-printf` action. See `man find`

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '*.jp*g' -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: I don't use GNU, my full script is find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '*.jp*g' ! -path "*/excluded/*" -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 -n1 -P3 sh -c 'exiv2 -q  -K Xmp.dc.creator -K Xmp.photoshop.Credit -Pv "$1" > "/Users/adm/Desktop/$1.out"' -- {}. I've tried to use | sed 's|^./||'  but it's not working with -print0

Comment: I've checked your answer on server and it's working good! locally I have macos and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can run the output of `find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -iname '*.jp*g'` through e.g. `sed`:

```
% mkdir f1 f2; touch f1/abc f2/def
% find . -type f |sed -e 's:.*/:./:' 
./def
./abc
```

But if you need to do that for NUL-separated "lines", you need a sed that supports that, e.g. `sed -z` with GNU sed.

Alternatively, you could remove the prefix within the shell command later with the `${var##pattern}` expansion which removes the longest matching prefix from the value.

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 sh -c 'echo "./${1##*/}"' -- {}
./def
./abc
```